# Deploying .war from nexus to weblogic using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, weblogic, nexus

i have jenkins and nexus running on docker-compose
i also have a weblogic 12.2.1.4 container running separately on the same machine.

I want to retrieve .war files from Nexus and deploy them to the weblogic container using Jenkins.

Do you have any idea how i can achieve this ?

I have managed to retrieve .war from Nexus using a wget command and it gets downloaded to the workspace correctly.

I looked at the WebLogic Deployment plugin and it's asking for these two fields that i don't know how to fill
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cnQg.png

Does any one know how to fill those parameters in order to continue using the plugin ?

Comment: Have a look into the documentation of the plugin, hope it will help you https://plugins.jenkins.io/weblogic-deployer-plugin/

Comment: Thank you sir, i already did, but i still couldn't find a way to specify the path of the weblogic jar when it's found in a different container !